# Setting a comfortable map view from dynamic points in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet to plot a map of crowd-sourced points (likely taking the form of GeoJSON Features). The only thing I know ahead of time is that they're generally close together, but I don't necessarily know how many there are. Does Leaflet provide method(s) for setting center and zoom dynamically at the time of initialization, or do I have to do the math on my own?

Comment: Look into the leaflet doc. [fitBounds](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-fitbounds), [setView](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-setview), [setZoom](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-setzoom). If you want to get the center of all points you have to calc by your self. A good library is turfjs centroid